# Python binascii.crc32() to PHP crc()

Tags: php, python, crc32

I have this line of Python that I want to convert to PHP

```
code = '%08x' % (binascii.crc32(summ) & 0xffffffffL)
```

As I understand, the php equivalent of `binascii.crc32` is `crc32()` and I might be wrong but `0xffffffffL` makes the signed integer positive so I would use `abs()`

I have tried this but I get no output not even an error message

```
$code = '%08x' % abs(crc($summ));
```

What is the correct way to get the output of the python but using php?

**UPDATE:**

I've now created and run a Python script and also a PHP equivalent and the output is slightly off.

Python

```
import binascii

file = open("test.json","r")
source = file.read()

key1 = 'Y3xFZ4'
key2 = 'ABC123'

summ = bytes(source + key1 + key2, encoding='utf-8')

print (binascii.crc32(summ))

code = '%08x' % (binascii.crc32(summ) & 0xfffffff)

print (code)

file.close()
```

Output

> 2416307871 0005ee9f

PHP

```
$json = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }';

$summ = $json . 'Y3xFZ4' . 'ABC123';

$test = sprintf("%u", crc32($summ));

$code = dechex((float) $test);

echo $test . ' ' . $code;
```

Output

> 2416307871 9005ee9f

What could be causing the difference at the beginning of the final output

Comment: You're looking for `sprintf`, the equivalent to Python's `%` string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your `& 0xfffffff` is missing an `f`.